# Tooltip Bootstrap 5.2/5.3 still not working in my end

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I build html web using bootstrap 5.2, and when I use the tooltip according to the instructions in the bootstrap doc but it doesn't work.

Error response in mozilla console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: bootstrap is not defined
> tooltipList

Code bootstrap javascript:

```
<script>
var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]'))
var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl)
})
</script>
```

Call in html

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap-5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css?v=5.3.0">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.min.js" defer=""></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bootstrap-5.3.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" defer=""></script>
<script>
  const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
  const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))
</script>
```

Has been try bootstrap 5.2 and 5.30 still not work, but popover working fine.

Comment: Looking to your code i can see that even bootstrap stylesheet is not applied to button so please check whether you provide correct path to css and js too.

Comment: @PatelHarsh That's because he probably copy/pasted from his local project, sadly most people don't spend even minutes trying their code ([Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) before posting.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for elements that have not been loaded yet, therefore, you should wait until the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction) loads. I'm going to use [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) event.

Here's the code:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]');
    const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map((tooltipTriggerEl) => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl));
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

For some reason, adding [`type="module"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type) on [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) works too. I only recommend this if you are using some [modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) in your `<script>` too (2 in 1) and you wouldn't need `DOMContentLoaded`.

So here's the code too:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">Tooltip on top</button>
<script type="module">
    const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]');
    const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map((tooltipTriggerEl) => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl));
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Adding module to script working. Thanks for sharing.